# Hide process icon from TaskBar

Tags: c#, taskbar, system.diagnostics

I'm writing a c# program that starts the touch keyboard process.

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "osk.exe");
```

I don't want that this process icon is shown in the task bar. The code:

```
ShowInTaskBar = false;
```

doesn't work because this isn't a Form but a process. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:I saw the example at [Hide icon of working process in TaskBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726826/hide-icon-of-working-process-in-taskbar) and i try to do it in C# but it still doesn't work.

My only doubt is about WS_EX_APPWINDOW because in C# i can't set the value &H40000 to an inttype, so i've looked in the web and i try to set ` const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000;

howhever the style variable values 0 after call

```
int style = (GetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW) ;
```

any ideas?

Comment: same as question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508149/processstartinfo-windowstyle-c-sharp

Comment: You are talking about the built-in on-screen keyboard from windows??

Comment: From the MSDN-Board:
"This is not possible because it can raise a security theft to the operating system. I am not sure if using Kernel32.DLL this can be done but I will not recommend you of this approach as it are against security best practices you can refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx"

Comment: this seems to be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726826/hide-icon-of-working-process-in-taskbar

Comment: @bash.d Yeah i'm talking abou it